# Change the string names in spinner dynamically from previous spinner chosen item

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to change the string names in spinner dynamically android from previous spinner chosen item.

This is my Activity class:

```
public class SelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final String LOG = "Selection";
    private Spinner spBranch;
    private Spinner spSection;
    private Spinner spSemester,spSubject;
    private Button btnSend;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        spBranch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spBranch1);
        spSection = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spSection1);
        spSemester = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spSemester1);
        spSubject=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spSubject1);
        String[] items1 = new String[]{"CSE", "EEE", "EE", "ECE", "MECH", "CIVIL"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items1);
        spBranch.setAdapter(adapter1);
        String[] items2 = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items2);
        spSection.setAdapter(adapter2);
        String[] items3 = new String[]{"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items3);
        spSemester.setAdapter(adapter3);

        String[] items4 = new String[]{"Math 1", "Programming in C", "Thermodynamics", "Communication English", "Physics", "Basic Electronics"};
        String[] items5 = new String[]{"Chemistry", "Data Structure", "Mechanics", "Buiseness English", "Basic Electrical Engineering l ", "Math 2"};
        if(spSemester.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1st"))
        {

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items4);
            spSubject.setAdapter(adapter4);

        }
        else{

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items5);
            spSubject.setAdapter(adapter4);

        }
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    } 



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(SelectionActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        HashMap postData = new HashMap();
        postData.put("txtBranch", spBranch.getSelectedItem().toString());
        postData.put("txtSection", spSection.getSelectedItem().toString());
        postData.put("txtSemester", spSemester.getSelectedItem().toString());

    }
}
```

I am getting Error at r this line `spSubject.setAdapter(adapter4);`
New to andorid, so is there any other way to do this

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: I suggest using more descriptive names than `items1`, `items2`, etc. For example, `items1` could be `strBranch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that all of the code you have posted will run immediately when the `Activity` is created. This is the whole point of the `onCreate()` method. Nothing will happen when the user selects a new item in any of the `Spinner`s. If you want the `Spinner`s to change more dynamically, you need to add appropriate event listeners. In particular, you need to implement [AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html). An example is shown [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener). I suggest creating separate classes which implement the listener interface rather than implementing it on your activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to know if first index in spSemester spinner is selected or not

```
if(spSemester.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)
{

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items4);
    spSubject.setAdapter(adapter4);

 }
 else{

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items5);
                spSubject.setAdapter(adapter4);

}
```

Comment: In the same place you wrote the first one. I just edited the if else part. That is why didn't post the whole code.